# Enquiring as to the origins of my name (Naufal)

Tags: history, names

Assalamu alaikum

I’ve had the given name ‘Naufal’ since childhood. I’m an adult now and for the first time I have enquired the origins of my name. And the only individual in Islamic history who shares my given name that I can find is **Nawfal ibn Khuwaylid**. Who is described thus:

> However, Nawfal opposed Muhammad and was known as "a satan of the
> Quraysh". At one time he bound Abu Bakr and Talha ibn Ubayd-Allah with
> a rope. Due to this, those two became known as Al-Qareenayn, "the two
> tied together".
>
> He was killed by Ali during the battle of Badr in 624.

The only other I know of is Waraqah ibn Nawfal.

Does my name truly only have this origin in Islamic history?

Please lend me some advice dear brothers and sisters, if this is the only origin in our history, then I would consider changing it, despite what it costs me. I want my name to match my faith.

Jazak Allah Khair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nawfal is an Arabic name. It was also the name of some of the sahaba such as:

- **Nawfal bin Mu'awiyah** ( نوفل بن معاوية بن عروة ). He accepted Islam at or before the conquest of Makkah and took part in the battles of Hunain and Taif; and the Hajj under Abu Bakr in 9 AH and later the the farewell Hajj under the Prophet ﷺ. He is a narrator of Hadith in Bukhari Muslim and [Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai:480) etc. Died in the time of Yazid.
- **Nawfal ibn al-Harith ibn Abdul Muttalib** ( نوفل بن الحارث بن عبد المطلب ) was the first cousin of the Prophet ﷺ. He was among the prisoners of Bani Hashim captured in the Battle of Badr - alongwith Abbas and Aqil, and accepted Islam after that. He migrated to Medinah around the time of the battle of Khandaq and took part in Hudaibiya, the conquest of Makkah, Hunain and Taif. Donated three thousand spears for the battle of Hunain and was among those who remained steadfast in this battle. He is mentioned in the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1072a) of prohibition of Zakat for the Ahl al-Bayt where the prophet asked him to marry his daughter to the son of Rabi'a. Died during the caliphate of Umar ibn al-Khatab who led his funeral, and is buried in al-Baqi.
- **Nawfal bin Abdullah  bin Nadla** ( نوفل بن عبد الله بن نضلة ) from the Ansar, from the tribe of Banu Khazraj. He was a veteran of the Badr and a martyr of Uhad.

Further see *Al-Isabah fi tamyiz al Sahabah* [page 378 - 380](https://ia801306.us.archive.org/28/items/FP22226/06_22231.pdf#page=378).

There is nothing wrong with keeping this name, and there is no reason to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Nawfal is an Arabic name and has different meanings in Arabic :

- Nawfal نوفل (as noun) : Sea.
- Nawfal نوفل (as adjective): generous "for man".
- Nawfal نوفل (as adjective): charming "for child".

and it's a good meanings , and as it's mentioned there were some of Sahaba share the same name "Nawfal" , so there is no reason to change it.

some believes that we may share some of characteristic of our names ,
so I ask Allah you have generosity in your personality as it's in your name.